# Right place for .so files

Tags: filesystem

I'm compiling a few modules for apache where is the best place to put them on OSX systems? It seems that root user doesn't have permissions to write on /usr/local.

Comment: Root user does have permissions to write to any directory

Comment: @Mark, this is not true on OSX:
$ sudo mv /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib1 
 results on 
mv: rename /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib to /usr/lib/libiodbcinst.dylib1: Operation not permitted

Comment: Sorry I forgot SIP - however /usr/local is not protected by SIP so that directory is writeable to by root

Comment: So I need to compile everything with --prefix=/usr/local and when you talk about SIP you mean System Integrity Protection (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899), right? thank you.

Comment: Most things have that prefix by default as that is **THE** Unix place to installed - and yes SIP is what you defined

Answer (score 1):

I never understood why "shared" libraries that are exclusive for one application should mess up a system folder. I would create a `modules` folder inside apache, add it to the `dyld` path and run `update_dyld_shared_cache`. When I want to remove the software one day, I just delete the folder in one place.